# In Python pyngrok error for .replace method

Tags: python, ngrok, pyngrok

I get an error on this line:

```
link = ngrok.connect(4040,"http").replace("http","https")
```

Error:

> Instance of 'NgrokTunnel' has no 'replace' member

Comment: Is `ngrok.connect(4040,"http")` a string? What does it output?

Comment: i want make a server on port 4040 and by ngrok make a link on  port and when in link saw http change to https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested it.

Your `link` is no string. You have to convert it into a string in order to replace text.

This works with the function str().

```
link = str(ngrok.connect()).replace("http", "https")
```

Comment: nice to hear, can you verify my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not quite correct, as the string you'll end up with is `[<NgrokTunnel: "https://<public_sub>.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:80">]` when the string you want is just the `https://<public_sub>.ngrok.io` part.

The [`NgrokTunnel` object](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyngrok.ngrok.NgrokTunnel) has a `public_url` attribute, which is what you want, so do this:

```
link = ngrok.connect(4040, "http").public_url.replace("http","https")
```

Moreover, if you don't even need the `http` port opened, this will just give you the `https` link by only opening a single tunnel, no need to manipulate the string:

```
link = ngrok.connect(4040, bind_tls=True).public_url
```

It's worth noting the accepted answer *will* work if you are using an [older version of `pyngrok` (pre-5.0.0 release)](https://github.com/alexdlaird/pyngrok/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).